# Extend multiple classes at once

Tags: ruby

I want to share a method amongst all Ruby's data object classes. That is to say the following classes:

- Hash
- String
- Number
- Array

Firstly, any classes I've missed out?

Secondly, how can I share `my_method` amongst all classes at once?

```
class Hash
    def my_method
       "hi"
    end
end

class String
    def my_method
       "hi"
    end
end

class Number
    def my_method
       "hi"
    end
end

class Array
    def my_method
       "hi"
    end
end
```

Comment: You misspelled one of the class names (`Numeric`). :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what modules are for:

```
module MyModule
  def my_method
   "hi"
  end
end

class Hash
  include MyModule
 end

class String
  include MyModule
end

...
```

You can also make it shorter with some metaprograming:

```
[Hash, String, Number, Array].each do |klass|
  klass.instance_eval do
    include MyModule
  end
end
```

In newer ruby versions (since ruby 2.1.0), `include` is no longer private method, hence you can simplify the above to:

```
[Hash, String, Number, Array].each do |klass|
  klass.include MyModule
end
```

Another way to achieve this is to include it within the parent class, like Object:

```
class Object
  def my_method
   "hi"
  end 
end

{}.my_method
```

This however will add this method to all the classes and will be available everywhere, so be careful.

Regarding whether you missed any classes - you missed tones of it, it all depends on what are you actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: You don’t need to reopen any classes or use `instance_eval` — you can just do  e.g. `Hash.include MyModule`.

Comment: @matt - `include` is class private method, at least in ruby 1.9.3 and ruby 2.0.0, and I prefer to open the class rather than calling send. In ruby 2.1.1 include is public method, will need to scan the changelog.

Comment: Found it: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8846 and https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/26766ee89c31b16be74803c08cb0d2de2d2fc58e.

Comment: Clear, complete answer.  Good one! I think `Number` should be `Numeric`.

Comment: Even for Ruby versions < 2.1, you don't need metaprogramming: `klass.send(:include, MyModule)`.